# MATLAB + Python Ideas?

Tags: python, matlab

I have been noticing a lot of necessary functions that are present in MATLAB but seem to not exist in Python. I am planning to make a Package or Master Class containing all of these functions and was wondering on any specifics Y'all might have or would like in the Package. If this has already been done, can I please have the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For *Python-as-a-Matlab-replacement*, the two must-have places to look at are:

- **python(x,y)** - http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/ - "*is a free scientific and engineering development software for numerical computations, data analysis and data visualization based on Python programming language, Qt graphical user interfaces and Spyder interactive scientific development environment.*"
- **Sage** - http://www.sagemath.org/ - "*is a free open-source mathematics software system licensed under the GPL. It combines the power of many existing open-source packages into a common Python-based interface.*". Its mission is "*Creating a viable free open source alternative to Magma, Maple, Mathematica and Matlab*"

Both combine the most popular scientific libraries Python offers, along with GUI and plotting tools, into a single whole that looks quite like Matlab (interactive interface included).

Answer (score 2):

I moved smoothly from MATLAB to python some years ago, and never looked back.  Almost all of the stuff is available in libraries `scipy` and `matplotlib`.  What functions in particular are you having trouble finding?

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

[Scipy](https://scipy.org/)

Also see this helpful guide [numpy for matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).